# Hide column from datagrid without button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have datagrid that his itemsource is datatable, I am trying to collapse some columns, it works only from button click.

**This doesn't work:**

When I invoke load function, it loads the data to `myDataTable` from the database, but it doesn't collapse the column from the datagrid

```
void Load()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    myDataTable = Query();  // <--- the Query function returns datatable
    My_DataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
    CollapseDGColumn("SomeCulumnName", My_DataGrid);
}

// Gets datagrid and column name and collapse the column
void CollapseDGColumn(string columnToHide, DataGrid dg)
{
     foreach (var col in dg.Columns) // <-- dg.Columns count=0
         if (col.Header.ToString().Trim() == columnToHide.Trim())
             col.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

When I invoke CollapseDGColumn function  it says that `dg.Columns` count is `0` even that has data in the `myDataTable` .

**This code does work:**

If I invoke this Load function:

```
void Load()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    myDataTable = Query();  // <--- the Query function returns datatable
    My_DataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

And after I click the button:

```
void Collapse_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollapseDGColumn("SomeCulumnName", My_DataGrid);
}
```

How can I make option **1** work, I mean without the button?

Comment: Are columns being generated on-the-fly? `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add loaded event like: `<DataGrid Loaded=“myDg_Loaded” />`

In code behind:

```
void myDg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
     //collapse columns here
}
```